# How to customise exception handling in Spring Authorization Server for token endpoint

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to implements additional checks for a user which is exchanging code for tokens using "/oauth2/token" endpoint in Spring Authorization Server. And for this I need to provide custom error message, error code and provide specific http status(other than 400 or 500).

I see that the code exchange starts in `OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter` but it has a strict exception hanling like

```
private void sendErrorResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException { ... }
```

and it can not be overridden as well as can not be set

```
private AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler = this::sendErrorResponse;
```

So I can extend from `OAuth2AuthenticationException` but it does not suite as I can not control the status and the response body.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I should read [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/protocol-endpoints.html#oauth2-token-endpoint) more carefully.

I still have to extend from `AuthenticationException` but I also have full controll over failure so adding custom body/code/status

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer =
            new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer();
    http.apply(authorizationServerConfigurer);

    authorizationServerConfigurer
            .tokenEndpoint(tokenEndpoint ->
                    ((OAuth2TokenEndpointConfigurer)tokenEndpoint).errorResponseHandler(errorResponseHandler)// instance of AuthenticationFailureHandler
            );

    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the error msg to be able to identify the issue. like invalid-scope. As exception.getMessage returns null

Comment: Doc link is broken...

Comment: 5 minutes edit comments limit ;( 
See [Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/protocol-endpoints.html)

Answer (score 0):

security config:

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(
        HttpSecurity http,
        UserTokenRepository userTokenRepository,
        CustomEncoder customEncoder,
        SessionService sessionService,
        CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler errorResponseHandler) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

    http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
            .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .tokenEndpoint(
                    oAuth2TokenEndpointConfigurer -> oAuth2TokenEndpointConfigurer
                            .accessTokenResponseHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler(userTokenRepository, customEncoder))
                            .errorResponseHandler(errorResponseHandler));}
```

and handler:

```
@Component
```

public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException {
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
response.getWriter().write("Authentication failed ! Check your credentials/inserted data.");
}
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).